# How to configure an URL for a determined asmx web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm not sure if it's properly asked but here's my situation:
I have a WebService which file name is `Service1.asmx` and this is accesed by the browser with the following URL: `http://localhost:4444/Service1.asmx`; what I'm trying to achieve is accessing it not by the filename of the service but by some kind of alias:

```
http://localhost:4444/ws1
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601185/asp-net-3-5-routing-to-webservice